# Why am I receiving 'type mismatch error' for this code?

Tags: type-mismatch

I am trying to specify for a range of cells to show #N/A if character results are not shown, and another range of cells to show  #DIV/0! if numeric results are not shown. Below is the code which causes me to receive 'Type mismatch' error. How should I edit this?

```
Sub novalue()

  Dim x As Integer

  For x = 2 To 100

  If Cells(x, 7).Value = 0 Then
     Cells(x, 7).Value = "#N/A"

  ElseIf Cells(x, 8).Value = 0 Then
     Cells(x, 8).Value = "#N/A"

  End If

Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: You are comparing a variant object to a String. This is the root of type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code please :

```
Sub novalue()
For Each cell In Range("A1:C100")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "#N/A"
    End If
Next cell
For Each cell In Range("D1:BV100")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "#DIV/0!"
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```